# Why was Bugs able to see Tom in his true form?

Tags: the-matrix

To all people other than Tiffany and himself, Tom Anderson was made to appear as an old man. How come Bugs saw him in his true shape when Tom jumped off the roof? Was this some Matrix bug unintended by the machines, and if so, what (could have) caused it?

Comment: Neo saw Tiffany as Trinity (reflected in the tabletop at the café). I'm guessing that the residual self-images just glitch occasionally